# Can't proceed with_items and register

Tags: ansible

Here is the problem I have. I am running the following playbook

```yaml
- name: Check for RSA-Key existence
  stat:
    path: /opt/cert/{{item.username}}.key
  with_items: "{{roles}}"
  register: rsa
    
- name: debug
  debug:
    var: item.stat.exists
  loop: "{{rsa.results}}"
    
- name: Generate RSA-Key
  community.crypto.openssl_privatekey:
    path: /opt/cert/{{item.username}}.key
    size: 2048
  when: item.stat.exists == False
  with_items:
    - "{{roles}}"
    - "{{rsa.results}}"
```

This is the error I receive:

> The error was: error while evaluating conditional (item.stat.exists == False): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stat'

The debug task is not firing any error

> "item.stat.exists": true

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix my playbook to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

Replace all your tasks with a single one:

```yaml
- name: Generate RSA-Key or check they exist
  community.crypto.openssl_privatekey:
    path: /opt/cert/{{ item.username }}.key
    size: 2048
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ roles }}"
```

## Problem with your last loop in original example

I don't know what you are trying to do exactly when writing the following in your last task:

```yaml
  with_items:
    - "{{roles}}"
    - "{{rsa.results}}"
```

What I know is the actual result: you are looping over a single list made of `roles` elements at the beginning followed by `rsa.results` elements. Since I am pretty sure no elements in your `roles` list has a `stat.exists` entry, the error you get is quite expected.

Once you have looped over an original list (e.g. `roles`) and registered the result of the tasks (in e.g. `rsa`), you actually have all the information you need inside that registered var. `rsa.results` is a list of individual results. In each elements, you will find all the keys returned by the module you ran (e.g. `stat`) **and** an `item` key holding the original element that was used in the loop (i.e. an entry of your original `roles` list).

I strongly suggest you study this by yourself with most attention by looking at the entire variable to see how it is globally structured:

```yaml
- name: Show my entire registered var
  debug:
    var: rsa
```

Once you have looked at your incoming data, it will become obvious that you should modify your last task as the following (note the `item.item` referencing the original element from previous loop):

```yaml
- name: Generate RSA-Key
  community.crypto.openssl_privatekey:
    path: /opt/cert/{{ item.item.username }}.key
    size: 2048
  when: not item.stat.exists  # Comparing to explicit False is bad use this instead
  with_items: "{{ rsa.results }}"
```

## Using `stat` here is an overkill

To go further, if all the above actually answers your direct question, it does not make much sense in Ansible world. You are doing a bunch of work that Ansible is already doing behind the scene for you.

The `community.crypto.openssl_privatekey` module create keys idempotently, i.e. it will create the key only if it doesn't exist and report `changed` or do nothing if the key already exists and report `ok`. So you can basically reduce all of your 3 tasks example to a **single task**

```yaml
- name: Generate RSA-Key or check they exist
  community.crypto.openssl_privatekey:
    path: /opt/cert/{{ item.username }}.key
    size: 2048
    state: present # This is not necessary (default) but good practice
  with_items: "{{ roles }}"
```

## Consider changing your var name

Last, I'd like to mention that `roles` is actually a reserved name in Ansible. So defining a var with that name should issue a warning in current ansible version, and will probably be deprecated in some time.

---

Refs:

- [registering variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables)
- [registering variables with a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop)

Comment: "if all the above actually answers your direct question" - yes it is, you detailed response сlaryfied this situation for me. I'm quite new in Ansible, i read the documentation, but there are still many points that I don't quite understand. Thanks to your answer, now there are 1 less of them. I feel myself silly that a forgot about "state", in this 2 days i tried so many variations of this task that my mind have stuck. Now, with your explanation i see it clear, thanks you!